# python testing with a imported module

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I'm fairly new to using mock and testing in general. This is my first attempt to mock a whole imported module. So for example I have

```
try:
    import redis
except:
    redis = None
```

Then later on in the code I check for redis

```
if redis is None:
     return
```

How can I set a mock object or class to the redis namespace so I don't have to install redis on my CI server?

Answer (score 0):

Names are just names, and you can assign anything to the 'redis' name at file/global scope, using either `import` or plain old assignment.

Like so:

```
import mock_redis as redis
```

...or so:

```
def mock_redis(): pass
```

BTW, your exception clause should be narrowed to handle only `ImportError`.